# cmake add_custom_command is aways out of date

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I have the problem that add_custom_command is always out of date and therefore runs on every build. the custom command runs a tool that is a target of the same project to generate a file that is used by another target:

```
add_executable(GeneratorTool main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT generated.h
    COMMAND GeneratorTool
    DEPENDS main.cpp
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "** GeneratorTool **"
)

add_library(MyLib STATIC generated.h ...)
```

In the build output (visual studio 2010) I always see ** GeneratorTool **. I would expect that it does not build again once generated.h exists and is newer than main.cpp.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can put `DEPENDS` on GeneratorTool in your `add_custom_command` instead of `main.cpp` . `GeneratorTool` already depends `main.cpp` .

Then most likely it is the location of `generated.h` which is ambiguous which forces the rebuilt of generated.h.

Make sure that MyLib looks for the `generated.h` in the right place.

My blind guess is to try:

```
add_library(MyLib STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated.h ...)
```

Comment: also add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated.h ...) may be necessary

Comment: In case someone stumbles across this: never output generated stuff into the source tree, always use the build tree, which can be references via `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing it could be - make sure the command is generating *all* `OUTPUT` files. If you generator is failing to generate even one of them, it will run every time (this was my problem).